# Find special point

Tags: geometry

Given that there are a set of un-ordered points $P_i(x_i,y_i),\quad i=0,\cdots,n$, now I would like find a special point $M$ that satisfies that $MP_i$ have no intersections with the boundary generate of these ordered points.

The first method I come out is the averaging technique, i.e.
$$
x_M=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^{n}x_i\\
y_M=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^{n}y_i
$$

However, sometimes it generates a wrong result, for instance

[image]

Here is a workaround that by my eyes

[image]

Comment: This is not always possible. Let's say the boundary you generated can be approximated by a polygon with $n$ sides. As long as $n \ge 6$, you may run
into trouble to find a single $M$ where all $P_i$ are visible.
Your problem is related to the [art gallery problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem). Given any $n$-gon, there are algorithms which can find at most $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \right\rfloor$ points $M_j$ so that all $P_i$ is visible to at least one of the $M_j$. Look at references in above link and see whether that helps.

Comment: @achillehui OK, thanks a bunch for your help:)

Comment: @achillehui BTW, are you Chinese?

Comment: @achillehui Why do you think "unfortunately"?